Jetpack Navigation Compose incorrect transition animation
When using NavHost, sometimes incorrect animations appear, but not when using AnimatedContent.
Navigation compose version: 2.8.0-alpha05
Compose ui version: 1.7.0-beta04
Kotlin version: 2.0.0
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
//    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar {
                TabNavigationItem(state, Tab.Home)
                TabNavigationItem(state, Tab.Favorites)
                TabNavigationItem(state, Tab.Profile)
            }
        },
    ) {
        //Works well
        AnimatedContent(
            state.value,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it),
            transitionSpec = {
                (fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(220, delayMillis = 90))
                    .togetherWith(fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(220, delayMillis = 90))))
            },
        ) { target ->
            when (target) {
                0 -> HomeScreen()
                1 -> FavoritesScreen()
                else -> ProfileScreen()
            }
        }

        //Sometimes incorrect animation
//        NavHost(
//            navController = navController,
//            startDestination = Tab.Home.route,
//            modifier = Modifier.padding(it),
//        ) {
//            homeDestination()
//            favoritesDestination()
//            profileDestination()
//        }
    }
}


